# C# TCP Socket Send has long delay with small packets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a problem with sending TCP data to a small window TCP stack on an 8 bit device. I have a utility that sends JSON configuration files to a device running a very lite TCP/IP stack on an 8 bit processor. The send/receive buffers on the 8 bit device are only 32 bytes in length. Speed is not a huge concern but I am noticing that if I send data to the device using the C# configuration utility, there is a very consistent 5 second delay between 32 byte packets of data. In fact, it seems to fragment and get out of sync where it sends 32 bytes initially, then sends 31 bytes, then 1 byte, then 31 bytes, and so on until all bytes are sent. This is all monitored in a Wireshark session trying to troubleshoot and diagnose what is going on. The weird thing is that if I use a telnet session to send the same data, there are no pauses at all.

So, what is the C# socket `Send` method doing differently than a paste into a CMD telnet session? I have the socket setup with `NoDelay = true` to disable the Nagle algorithm. I can't imagine that the problem is on the device side since it works perfectly when using the CMD telnet session. It seems really odd that it is exactly 5 seconds between packets according to Wireshark.

This same utility has been used on lots of other devices without any pauses or issues. I think that somehow the small MSS of 32 bytes seems to be causing the TCP socket to behave differently with this new device.

Here is the simple setup and call:

```
public class DeviceConnection : IDisposable
{
    private Socket m_socket = null;

    public bool Connect(string host, ushort port, int timeout = 10000)
    {
        m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Disable the Nagle Algorithm for this tcp socket.
        m_socket.NoDelay = true;

        // Close immediately, but gracefully
        //m_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, true);

        // Set the timeout for synchronous receive methods to  
        // 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds.)
        m_socket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        //m_socket.SendTimeout = timeout;

        IPAddress address;
        IAsyncResult result = null;
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(host, out address))
        {
            //Valid IP, with address containing the IP
            result = m_socket.BeginConnect(address, port, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //Invalid IP, must be host name, not IP address
            result = m_socket.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null);
        }

        bool success = false;
        if (result != null)
        {
            success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true);
        }
        if (!m_socket.Connected)
        {
            m_socket.Close();
        }

        return m_socket.Connected;
    }

    public void SendString(string s)
    {
        if (m_socket != null && m_socket.Connected)
        {
            byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            m_socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: *`m_socket.Send(....)`* - you blindly assume that everything gets send by not checking the return value of `Send`.

Comment: Also you need to `Flush` if you want to make sure data is sent. A common misunderstanding is that `Send` will send exactly one packet. TCP is a *stream* not a bunch of packets, so it will just batch them out, possibly splitting or joining them across packets.

Comment: Delays probably mean that C# utility just floods your device, latter can't handle income stream quickly. Then sending queue of C# client becomes full - Socket.Send method often blocks your thread, these blocks are your Wireshark delays. Try opposite - enable Nagle's algorithm. Ps: good tip about flush.

Comment: The negotiation of the TCP connection correctly sets up the window sizes as I can see in the Wireshark log. So, the C# side of the TCP stack is only sending packets with a max of 32 bytes of data. So, I don't think flooding is happening. And there are not a bunch of re-transmits. There's just a long pause between sets of packets even though the device has immediately ACK'd the receipt of the segment. And the `Send` is succeeding. All bytes eventually get there. But when sending about 300 bytes the process takes almost 60 seconds.

Comment: I am still going to try the suggestions, though. It is easy to enable Nagle and do flushes. I do think that the C# `Send` is blocking which is causing the pauses, I just don't understand why it is blocking if the device has already ACK'd the last segment of data. It should be ready to send the next segment of bytes. I need to collect a Wireshark log and provide that. Maybe that will give a better idea of what I am seeing.

Comment: Are you actually setting the MTU at 32 bytes?

Comment: I am not setting the MTU. I am letting the negotiation handle setting the MSS and this seems to be working according to the Wireshark session. I can try explicitly setting the MTU on the C# client.

Comment: No don't set the MTU manually. I wonder if disabling Nagle is not working. Maybe depends on your network driver, because TCP is offloaded. Check if you have the latest driver. To be honest, UDP is much better for this type of thing, because it only deals in single datagrams

Answer (score 0):

You are making a very common mistake with TCP, as used in C# and Winsock. It is not a series of packets, it is a continuous stream of bytes, and a single message may be split or joined over multiple network packets.

So in order to send a whole message in exactly one packet, you need to use `Flush`.

You should also use the much easier `TcpClient`, which abstracts away a lot of the complexity, and also use `async`.

```cs
public class DeviceConnection : IDisposable
{
    private TcpClient _client = null;

    public async Task Connect(string host, ushort port, int timeout = 10000)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient();

        // Disable the Nagle Algorithm for this tcp socket.
        _client.Client.NoDelay = true;

        // Set the timeout for synchronous receive methods to  
        // 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds.)
        _client.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

        await _client.ConnectAsync(host, port);
    }

    public async Task SendString(string s)
    {
        if (_client != null && _client.Connected)
        {
            byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            var stream = _client.GetStream();
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you dispose the `TcpClient` properly.

Ideally you should really use a proper framing mechanism for the messages, which means that they can always be understood by the receiver even when split across packets.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is required to view source code of NetworkStream.Flush. Cause of somewhere i read it is impossible to make such sort of granular control over OS level network stack from application level.

Comment: I do understand the nature of TCP/IP and it being a stream. The idea is that the stream is supposed to be guaranteed delivery with the implementation handled by the stack. The developer should not care what the sizes of the packets are, congestion, re-transmits, etc. And there is framing on the other side. There are bytes to indicate the parts of the data to be consumed and how much data is expected. Those bytes are being consumed as fast as the C# utility is sending them. The utility just strangely pauses for 5 seconds as segments are sent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may try to switch things over to the `TcpClient`. This utility has been around for quite a while, and could use an update. But for most connection scenarios, it has been very stable and efficient. I just think that the `TcpClient` is going to exhibit the same problems because it is using the same underlying TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Network traffic is as fast as its receiver fast at handling incoming data. Sender can be just a machine gun..So, there is a chance that there is a problem in that particular device only.

Comment: I think the problem is definitely that this device has the lowest buffer size that the C# client has ever interacted with. But the device itself is handling incoming data about as fast as expected. As mentioned, sending the data via a telnet session paste in a CMD terminal works just fine.